# missing reference? I already added

Tags: c#, reference

I'm trying to restore my DB via C# but I'm getting this error:

[image]

even that I have added reference to `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo`

[image]

Here my code:

```
void RestoreDatabase(String databaseName , String backUpFile , String serverName , String userName , String password)
    {
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server smoServer =
  new Server(new ServerConnection(server));

        Database db = smoServer.Databases['MyDataBase'];
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(db.PrimaryFilePath , 'MyDataBase.mdf');
        string logPath = Path.Combine(db.PrimaryFilePath , 'MyDataBase_Log.ldf');
        Restore restore = new Restore();
        BackupDeviceItem deviceItem =
            new BackupDeviceItem('d:\MyDATA.BAK' , DeviceType.File);
        restore.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
        restore.Database = backupDatabaseTo;
        restore.FileNumber = restoreFileNumber;
        restore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
        restore.ReplaceDatabase = true;
        restore.SqlRestore(smoServer);

        db = smoServer.Databases['MyDataBase'];
        db.SetOnline();
        smoServer.Refresh();
        db.Refresh();
    }
```

Please if someone familiar with C# and can answer this.

Comment: Try to restore your nuget packages once. If it doesn't work then, go to `users\<username>\.nuget` folder delete it and again `Restore nuget packages`

Comment: `using Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo;` ?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Probably the images of your error, we are a salty bunch

Comment: Maybe you need to add a reference to: Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll. See: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.aspx)

Comment: What's wrong with the images?

Comment: plz upvote I don't want to be blocked from SO

Comment: @RTExeption its just an extra click, also images aren't searchable

Comment: @RTExeption you wont get blocked for downvotes on question that i know, half the users here all day would get blocked, there would be noone left

Comment: It's extra click that explains better the question, If I will delete the images I will get the upvotes? plz I don't want to be blocked from SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Restore Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> The Restore object provides programmatic access to restore operations.
>
> **Namespace**:   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo
>
> **Assembly**: 
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended (in
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll)

So you will need

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll
```

I think you can find it here

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll/